# Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags Not Being Scraped For My Laravel Site

Tags: html, laravel, facebook, sharing

I am trying to add `og:type`, `og:title`, `og:image`, `og:description`, and `og:url` meta tags to my laravel page but none of them are being properly scraped by the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing).

I’ve already tried moving these meta tags around but the result from Facebook never changes.

Here’s a part of the HTML meta tags I have added:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The meta tags I have added are not being scraped properly and the debugger returns the following:

[image: Screenshot 2]

**P.S.**

For some reason, Facebook seems to be scraping my main page instead of the link I have provided. I am sure my link is publicly accessible.

Comment: Have you tried using double-quotes instead of single-quotes?

Comment: @JonathanGray, yes I already tried but did not work

Comment: @ChristianEsteves please [edit] your question and add the source code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, Facebook seems to be scraping my main page instead of the link I have provided.

Facebook is just doing what you’re telling it to:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dev.mafindoor.com">
```

From [the Open Graph docs](https://ogp.me/#metadata):

> `og:url` - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

When the Facebook crawler finds this tag, treats it like a [`<link rel="canonical">`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) tag - by treating the crawled page as an alias for the linked URL.

The `og:url` meta tag should be set to the preferred URL of the *current* page, not the entire website.

---

You can see this behaviour in the Facebook Sharing Debugger ([*link*](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mafindoor.com%2Fbuildings%2F4-sm-city-legazpi)):

[image: Facebook Sharing Debugger screenshot]

---

**PS:**

As it stands, one of your OG meta tags uses mixed single and double quotes, rendering it and all subsequent tags invalid:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content='website">
<meta property="og:title" content='Mafindoor - SM City Legazpi">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mafindoor.com/img/pages/screen2.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Thanks Mafindoor for helping me find my ways inside SM City Legazpi">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dev.mafindoor.com">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="329159957633823">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MTCoster. You saved my week :)

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess based on your images but try to use double quotes `content=""` and so on. I would place your og tags at the end of head section. OG title can possibly be ovverriden with `<title>` and og description with standard meta description tag.

I read og documentation and they advise to provide image dimensions:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="fav/og-thumb.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1240">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="650">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried but did not work. For some reason, it looks like Facebooks is scraping my main page instead of the link I have provided.